# Programmatically detect when a view is about to change.

Tags: ios

I'm attempting to implement an `auto-save` feature that will send a packet containing modified data over the network when the user changes views. The issue is that I have yet to find a way to figure out when the user is leaving the view, something such as:

```
method onChangeViewStart(param currentView, param nextView)
method onChangeViewFinish(param lastView, param currentView)
```

Does this exist? My navigation is using `UITabBarController`

Comment: do you know about `viewWillDisappear`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comment above, I feel like you are looking for `viewWillDisappear` which is a function already built into `UIViewController`.

Just add the following code into your view controller then add any custom logic below the comment.

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    // Your custom code here.
}
```

[Apple Documentation on UIViewController.viewWillDisappear](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillDisappear:)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean `UIViewController`? It has some useful functions for you: [Responding to View Events](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW46)

Comment: Please include the main point in the answer. Link only answers are problematic since the page linked to may disappear or change.